# What happens under the hood when creating objects in java and python

Tags: java, python

I recently started study Python after Java.

I learned that when creating objects  first a raw or uninitialised object must be created, and then the object must be initialised.

I concluded, first `__new()__` creates the raw object, then we needed `__init()__` a `self` parameter to initialise the raw object.

So my first question is in Java does the same process happens when creating an object.

And the second is as Python does, do Java compiler also adds a automatic parameter to it's methods to support `this`.  As the following:

```
class Test

    public Test(Test this){}

    public int method(Test this,int i){

        return i;

    }
```

Comment: Java uses the keyword [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), which functions as the equivalent of `self` in Python.

Comment: @Felipe so what I have illustrated above is correct then?

Comment: It's almost correct, because in Java you **must not** write `Test this` as first parameter (it is implied by the compiler)

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yeah it's a job of compiler then, thanks a lot it helped me!

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058499/what-occurs-when-object-is-created-in-java/17058715

Comment: Note, in Java, `this` is *not generally required* like it is in Python, because in Java, you declare fields and the compiler knows when a field is being referenced inside the scope of a method. In Python, you are required to use `self.field`. Furthermore, `this` is a keyword in Java, `self` is not a keyword, rather, it is a convention. In Python, it is *the first parameter of a method definition that holds special status*, and although you can name it whatever you want, you should use `self` to stick to convention

Answer (score 0):

This is a "reference variable" in Java that refers to current object. The compiler handles the usage of this inside the objects. For instance, when you create a class such as below:

```
public class Coordinates
{ 
    private int x; 
    private int y; 

    Coordinates(int x, int y) 
    { 
        this.x= x; 
        this.y = y; 
    } 

    void showCurrentLocation() 
    { 
        System.out.println("The coordinates are: x = " + x + "  y = " + y); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(11, 2); 
        coordinates.showCurrentLocation(); 
    } 
}
```

this.x will refer to the object's attribute x and the other x will refer to the input parameter. In both Java and C++, compiler also adds an automatic parameter to it's methods to support this as you have asked.

In order to observe yourself, I suggest you to use a debugger in Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea, you will see the this and you will see which variables' values it holds.